# Activating facebook auth dialog

Tags: php, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I am making a facebook app. I need the facebook users to authenticate my app before they can use it.

under settings for my app, I found a auth dialog box under facebook developers -> settings -> permissions.

I created this: http://i46.tinypic.com/34gwyn6.png

My question is then, how do I activate it?

When I test the application with a facebook account, I can never retrieve the userid from that user.

Comment: Are you using the PHP SDK or the JavaScript SDK, or another way to access Facebook's API? This might be a good place to start reading: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Comment: Hi, I am using the JavaScript SDK :) Sorry. This looks very correct. The only problem is, I don't like the login button. Do you know if there is any way, for the OAUTH dialog to just show, when the user opens the app ?

I found something like this:

    var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
        oauth_url += '?client_id=192352355546693';
        oauth_url += '&redirect_url=' + 'https://apps.facebook.com    /dewgwegwagenx/';
        oauth_url += '&scope=user_about_me';
    
        window.top.location = oauth_url;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings you made in your app dashboard do *only* affect [Authenticated Referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals) – when you handle login yourself in your app, you have to request permissions via the `scope` parameter.

And since you’re using the JS SDK already, just use [`FB.login`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) to trigger the Auth dialog for your app.